# How to wrap three divs for mobile device

Tags: css, html, mobile

I want to vertically wrap three divs if the device is a mobile. The issue I am having is with the border that separates all three divs. When this site is viewed on a large monitor, there will be 3 inline divs with 2 borders separating the columns at 100% height. When these divs wrap on a small screen, the border will not go to the bottom. Is there a way to do this so that when these divs wrap, both of the borders will touch the floor?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <style type="text/css">
            html,body {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
            }

            #left {
                float:left;
                width:33%;
                height:100%;
                min-width:300px;
                border-right:1px solid
            }

            #middle {
                float:left;
                width:33%;
                height:100%;
                min-width:300px;
                border-right:1px solid;
            }

            #right {
                float:left;
                width:33%;
                height:100%;
                min-width:300px;
                border-right:1px solid;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="height:100%">

            <div id="left">
                <div>1</div>
                <div>1</div>
                <div>1</div>
                <div>1</div>
                <div>1</div>
            </div>

            <div id="middle">
                <div>2</div>
                <div>1</div>
                <div>1</div>
                <div>1</div>
                <div>1</div>
            </div>

            <div id="right">
                <div>3</div>
                <div>1</div>
                <div>1</div>
                <div>1</div>
                <div>1</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
 height:100%;
```

from #left, #middle, #right and Define some margin like :

```
margin-bottom:10px;
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KsvgV/1/

Comment: I just tried that and now the borders are at the top of the page.

Comment: I didn't understand, what you want to say. Border is also managed equally.

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle. The problem with your solution is that my content is at 100% height and what you've provided doesn't push the borders to the ground

Comment: What I am trying to say is that if the screen is 1000px height, then the borders should also be 1000px height with no gaps in them

Comment: Wait... My mistake, Sushil. I removed the margin and it seems to look ok. Let me try this locally and I'll be right back.

Comment: Ohh, then you have to apply @media queries. Then you will be able to define heights for different mobile devices.

Comment: Follow my answer here : stackoverflow.com/questions/22087455/how-to-make-an-image-header-not-show-on-mobile/22087537?noredirect=1

Comment: OK, thanks Sushil. What you have given me will work better than what I currently have. I'll accept this as the right answer. Thanks for the link as well. Going there now

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, all you have to do is add `margin-bottom` to your style.

`margin-bottom:2%;`

well, to all of them  `#left,  #right and #middle,`
It would be better you use same class add them that will reduce css.

check out this, I have edit the code :

[http://jsfiddle.net/jdniki/3xr6v/](http://jsfiddle.net/jdniki/3xr6v/1/)